# exclude WEB-INF from a maven generated war

Tags: maven, web-applications, war, web-inf

How do I prevent the WEB-INF directory from being included in the .war package?

This does not work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/**</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This does not work, either.

```
        <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF</warSourceExcludes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a static HTML site with only .js, .css, and .html, I switched to the rar package format that only generates a META-INF. Then I added this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be incline to say that WEB-INF is not part of the *source* directory but is considered as a *resource*.

Therefore you should try with the *webResource* property instead:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Something like:

```
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
              <directory>resource2</directory>
              <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
              <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
```